# Setting custom GDAL tags using PROFILE=[GDALGeoTIFF]

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I am trying to write custom metadata to a Geotiff file using:

```
if dataset:
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
dst_ds = driver.CreateCopy('result_tiff', dataset, strict=0,
                           options=["PROFILE=GDALGeoTIFF"]
```

This will eventually be incoorperated into a Tkinter application where users can add and edit metadata in image files. I read on https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/tags/1.6.3/gdal/frmts/gtiff/frmt_gtiff.html that GDAL custom tags may be written using PROFILE=GDALGeoTIFF. I haven't found an example of how to do so.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: GDAL 1.6.3 is thirteen years old https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/Release/1.6.3-News! Read the current documentation first from https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html. Gdal_edit https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html#gdal-edit is a Python script that can set metadata tags and is probably useful as an example.

Comment: What metadata are you trying to write?  The PROFILE creation option only determines *where* GDAL writes its non standard metadata. If GDALGeoTIFF, the GDAL metadata gets written to the the TIFF file itself in a non standard TIFFTAG  (TIFFTAG_GDAL_METADATA ), for BASELINE and GeoTIFF, it will be written to an external aux.xml file.

Comment: Without getting into detail, I am trying to write metdata such as the country code and other info that is specific to my workplace. I am trying to write data to the TIFF file itself, not just to an external aux.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to add metadata into existing TIFF:

```
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Open("test.tif", gdal.GA_Update)
ds.SetMetadata({"COUNTRY_CODE": "foo"})
ds = None
```

Check the result with gdalinfo

```
gdalinfo test.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: test.tif
Size is 1198, 645
Coordinate System is:
...
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Point
  COUNTRY_CODE=foo
...
```